# How to Update another Input Field after selecting an Autocomplete option?

Tags: javascript, html, json, zipcode, form-fields

I am building a classifieds website where users can input their location information, which is then displayed on a Google Maps sidebar. However, the map does not display correctly unless a valid zip code is entered. I have tried to fix this, but have been unsuccessful. The problem is that many users do not know or ignore the zip code field.

To solve this issue, I want to store zip code information in a JSON file and use this data to automatically generate the appropriate zip code in the textfield when a user selects a state from a dropdown list. For example, if a user selects "Kuala Lumpur" from the list, the zip code "57000" should be automatically entered in the textfield using the data from the JSON file.

[My JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tamimi89/ucqujkm3/1/)

```
<label>State</label>
<select name="cp_state" id="cp_state" class="dropdownlist required"><option value="">-- Select --</option><option value="Kuala Lumpur" selected="selected">Kuala Lumpur</option><option value="Labuan">Labuan</option><option value="Malacca">Malacca</option>              </select>

<label>Zip/Postal Code </label>
<input name="cp_zipcode" id="cp_zipcode" type="text" class="text" placeholder="Enter zipcode" />
```

JSON data

```
[
  {
        "czipcode": "57000",
        "cstate": "Kuala Lumpur"
    },
    {
        "czipcode": "75000",
        "cstate": "Labuan"
    },
    {
        "czipcode": "87000",
        "ctate": "malacca"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my question by implementinig [jQuery Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and then modifying the code to update the zip code input field with the corresponding data from the JSON file whenever an autocomplete suggestion is selected.

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="city">City</label>
        <input id="city"/><br><br>

        <label for="zipcode">Zipcode</label>
        <input id="zipcode" type="text"/>
    </div>
      
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var data = [
            { "value": "Allentown","zipcode": "88459" },
            { "value": "Anchorage", "zipcode": "72815" },
            { "value": "Athens", "zipcode": "53861" },
            { "value": "Bellevue", "zipcode": "22183" },
            { "value": "Birmingham", "zipcode": "88235" }
        ];
        $('#city').autocomplete({
            source: data,    // lookup suggestion from data json
            delay: 500,      // delay in milliseconds before displaying suggestions
            minLength: 3,    // minimum number of characters before displaying suggestions
            select: function (event, suggestion) {
                $('#zipcode').val(suggestion.item.zipcode); // update input with respective zipcode
            }
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```